# Ubuntu installer always crashes when it's time to reboot

Tags: 16.04, system-installation, 17.04

I've having some trouble installing Ubuntu last few days. I've tried installing both 17.04 and 16.04 and had the same trouble. 
Installation goes nicely, but when it comes to the required restart, it crashes as soon as I click the button. If I wait, it shows the log in this:

[image]

If I force it to shut down, when I try to login Ubuntu, it crashes as soon as I login.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may have a memory hardware problem.

Go to http://www.memtest.org and download the free memory diagnostic and run at least one complete pass minimum.

**Update:**

The memory diagnostic seems to have passed OK.

Boot to the GRUB menu. Hit the <kbd>e</kbd> key to enter edit mode. Use the arrow keys to find the line that contains "quiet splash" and change it to read "quiet splash nomodeset". Then hit <kbd>F10</kbd> to exit and continue the boot.

Once booted, open the `Software & Updates` app. Select the `Additional Drivers` tab, and click the button to enable the Nvidia graphic driver. Then reboot and you should be OK.

Comment: I've done that and got 0 errors as you see [here](https://imgur.com/a/i44iz). Still having the same problems... I've tried so many things I have no idea what's wrong here...

Comment: Desktop or laptop? What make/model? Current BIOS/UEFI firmware? What's the memory config... total RAM, # RAM sticks, size of RAM sticks? What processors? Can you boot to emergency mode?

Comment: Most of those things I don't even know. Ok, it is a Clevo brand laptop, UEFI, 16gb ram, 2 sticks I think, i7 5th gen processor, dont know how to boot in emergency mode

Comment: It doesn't have a model/serial # tag on it? Boot to emergency mode by choosing `Additional Options` in the GRUB menu.

Comment: Yes, it does. It's a N150RD Clevo laptop

Comment: Just managed to start ubuntu through recovery mode but I still cannot start it directly through the first grub menu

Comment: It's still not booting, though... Only in recovery mode

Comment: @fff If you followed my update instructions exactly, and it still won't boot, then I'm out of ideas for you. Sorry.

Comment: There's a version of Memtest included in every Ubuntu installation and live system accessible from the boot menu. No need to download and set up proprietary software. Also, http://www.memtest86.org is offline.